# Is there a function to submit a wildcard search request via firebase firestore?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

For example, querying the collection `foo` with the query string `a*` should return any item in the collection that starts off with the letter *a*. I have a collection of U.S States in a firebase firestore collection and it connects to an iOS app written in `Swift` via the firestore API. Inside of a SearchResultsViewController users should be able to search for a state via a substring of that state. For example when a user types `a` into the searchText field, the results returned to them should be `[Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas]` because those states start off with the letter `a`. Each document has an id which is an Auto-ID given by firebase and a name which is the `name` field which contains the name of the state. The query will be run against the name field of the document.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what you're trying to do. An example would be helpful.  It would also be good to know what language you're using.

Comment: After the question gets improved, the answer will be "no, not for an arbitrary wildcard". If you can constrain the requirement to find an enumerated handful of substrings, or to a subarray of records sorted lexically, then yes.

Comment: @danh It's not necessarily a hard "no", depending on the specific requirements.  But it sure won't be a wildcard syntax.

Comment: I'm still not clear.  Are you saying the name of the state is the ID of the document? Or are you searching using a field in the document?  It will help if you give more detail about the structure of your documents.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming something like a `stateName` property in the docs (not the docs' ids), a subrange of a lexical ordering can be returned with a pair of `whereField` inequalities...

```
collectionRef.whereField("stateName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "A")
collectionRef.whereField("stateName", isLessThan: "B")
```

Note this isn't an arbitrary wildcard. It applies only to the starts of the strings and answers whatever falls into a range alphabetically.